# Allow application access to Azure AD protected URL without username/password

Tags: asp.net, azure, adal

Never thought I'd run into an issue of having **too much** documentation! I need help with picking the right information so I can read it, understand it, and follow it.

My scenario:

I have an ASP .NET Web Application that is hosted on mywebapp.azurewebsites.net
The web app has a full REST API at mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/dostuff/1

You can go to the site and perform all the CRUD stuff. You can also use desktop application to do the same.

I went ahead and enabled Azure AD authentication in Azure Portal. Now in order to do anything on the website, users need to sign in. It brings up the usual Microsoft Login popup and then upon successful authentication redirects back to the site.

But when it comes to the desktop app, I want the users to be able to use it without signing in. Somehow my desktop application needs to be able to make calls to the API/website and be authenticated!

At this point I am lost if there is something I need to do in manifest file, or in the web app, or elsewhere?

Most I was able to do is get an access token using client credentials/client secret.

I just need to know if what I am trying to achieve possible and which document explains the approach of doing so.

Comment: Ended up doing what the answer suggested. On the web app, I've created another controller (APIController) which exposed anonymous access to only the Get requests (all that my desktop client needs anyway). This way the actual website and it's functionality require login from user, but the desktop can do certain anonymous API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the fundamental problem you have is that a desktop app (like any public client) has no way of authenticating itself to AAD in a secure way.

You cannot use a client secret.
It is very easy to grab the secret from the executable, and that is basically your app's password.

You would have to make the API accept calls without authentication pretty much.

If authentication is required for access to the API,
then a user must authenticate in the app.

Comment: That makes sense. I do remember reading that you should not be putting the client secret in the code. Which is the same reason why I don't want to just put username/pw in the code. Is there a way to do what you said and just allow anonymous access on the API? I imagine it would be a matter of putting [Authorize (roles)] tag on some pages, but leaving API to allow anonymous?

Comment: As a follow up... you said "no way of authenticating itself to AAD in a secure way.", but what about insecure way? I imagine it should be harder to get client secret from code, than to just look at network traffic and get the API links which would otherwise have anonymous access. My issue is that even with postman and using client secret, the JWT I get does not seem to have any roles or permissions to access anything at all.

Comment: Yeah so in practice the threats are a bit different, but from a security standpoint using a secret from a non-trusted system is basically the same as if the key was compromised already or if no key was required at all. The JWT containing no permissions is kind of a separate problem to this. You can open a new question for that, and explain in detail how you have configured the app and API, and show the code you use to acquire the token.